# node js mysql query where id = ARRAY?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am working to fetch data of listed users and I have an array of users like

```
var result_user_id = [
  {
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "id": 20
  }
];
```

and I tried something like

```
connection.query( 
   "select * from `contents` where `user_is` IN "+ result_user_id, 
   function( err_user, result_user ) {

   }
);
```

but unable to fetch related data.
how to do that in node js.

Comment: Is the array you've posted the value of `result_user_id` ?

Comment: yes, in this format [
  {
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "id": 20
  }
] .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var o =[
  {
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "id": 20
  }
];
var arr = o.map( function(el) { return el.id; });
connection.query( "select * from `contents` where `user_is` IN ("+ connection.escape(arr)+")", function( err_user, result_user ) { });
```

input can be sanitized using connection.escape(), mysql.escape() or pool.escape(). please refer [this](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values) to sanitize input.

Comment: $ is not defined in node js. :(

Comment: dont concatenate strings to a query without string sanitation

Comment: @wasserholz I have changed code to fix the issue. If any modifications needed let me know or please edit it.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question is a little bit older, but I found it via googled and stumbled across the same problem. This is the easiest solution I found:

```
    var result_user_id = [
  {
    "id": 19
  },
  {
    "id": 20
  }
];

var result_array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < result_user_id; i++) {
      result_array[i] = result_user_id[i].id;
    }

connection.query( "select * from contents where user_is IN (?)", [result_array], function( err_user, result_user ) { });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to take advantage of safe escaping (?) you can do the following:

```js
 connection.query('SELECT FROM `contents` WHERE `user_is` IN (' + 
   Array(result_user_id.length + 1).join('?').split('').join(',') + ')', result_user_id.map(p => p.id), function(err, result_user){});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just take the variable `result_user_id` as is and put it into the sql. Try something like:

```
for (var i=0, len=result_user_id.length; i<len; i++){
   userIds += result_user_id[i].id + ",";
}
```

and then user the userIds instead of result_user_id in the sql you're trying to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with es6 syntax:

```
const inClause = ids.map(id=>"'"+id+"'").join();

const query =  `SELECT * FROM docs d WHERE d.id IN (${inClause})`;
```